# How can I extract string ‘abc.com’ from a string http://info@abc.com using SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I extract string ‘abc.com’ from a string http://info@abc.com using SQL server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more generalized variation to KM's response...

```
declare @s varchar(100)

select @s = 'http://info@abc.com'

select right(@s, len(@s) - charindex('@', @s))
```

This will locate the '@' in the string and grab everything to the right.  This is most likely MSSQL specific syntax.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL Server, try (assumes no nulls and string is found):

```
declare @x  varchar(100), @y varchar(100)
select @x='http://info@abc.com',@y='abc.com'
print SUBSTRING(@x,CHARINDEX(@y,@x),LEN(@y))
```

**EDIT**
based on Dave Carlile answer, these handles the case when @ is not present:

retunrs empty string when "@" is not present

```
declare @s varchar(100)
select @s = 'http://infoabc.com'
select right(@s, len(@s) - CASE WHEN charindex('@', @s)>0 then charindex('@', @s) ELSE len(@s) END)
```

returns null when "@" is not present

```
declare @s varchar(100)
select @s = 'http://infoabc.com'
select CASE WHEN charindex('@', @s)> 0 THEN right(@s, len(@s) - charindex('@', @s)) ELSE NULL END
```

Answer (score 0):

As Joel said, there is no real answer - it depends on the database you're using.

I assume you're looking for a regular expression, and not extracting the string "abc.com" specifically. I suppose there might be a database which would have a built-in function for regular expressions, but most probably wouldn't. Fortunately, most databases today allow you to incorporate your own code in another language (usually Java or .NET, again - depends on the database).

If your database allows it, you could use this kind of functionality in your SELECT statements.

Comment: Seems like you got your answer. :)